# What exactly is the LLVM C++ API

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I found it hard to understand the LLVM C++ API.
Is there any relationship between LLVM C++ API and LLVM IR? Also, how could one use the LLVM C++ API?

Comment: If you only want to generate the IR (and probably run some passes over it), you probably would be better off using the LLVM C bindings, they're nice, clean and minimalistic.

Answer (score 16):

To (greatly) simplify, LLVM is a C++ library for writing compilers. Its C++ API is the external interface users of the library employ to implement their compiler.

There's a degree of symmetry between LLVM IR and part of the LLVM C++ API - the part used to build IR. A very good resource for getting a feel for this symmetry is http://llvm.org/demo/. For example, you can compile this C code:

```
int factorial(int X) {
  if (X == 0) return 1;
  return X*factorial(X-1);
}
```

Into LLVM IR:

```
define i32 @factorial(i32 %X) nounwind uwtable readnone {
  %1 = icmp eq i32 %X, 0
  br i1 %1, label %tailrecurse._crit_edge, label %tailrecurse

tailrecurse:                                      ; preds = %tailrecurse, %0
  %X.tr2 = phi i32 [ %2, %tailrecurse ], [ %X, %0 ]
  %accumulator.tr1 = phi i32 [ %3, %tailrecurse ], [ 1, %0 ]
  %2 = add nsw i32 %X.tr2, -1
  %3 = mul nsw i32 %X.tr2, %accumulator.tr1
  %4 = icmp eq i32 %2, 0
  br i1 %4, label %tailrecurse._crit_edge, label %tailrecurse

tailrecurse._crit_edge:                           ; preds = %tailrecurse, %0
  %accumulator.tr.lcssa = phi i32 [ 1, %0 ], [ %3, %tailrecurse ]
  ret i32 %accumulator.tr.lcssa
}
```

As well as to C++ API calls (I won't paste it here because the output is long, but you can try it yourself). Doing this, you'll see, for example the `icmp` instruction from the IR code above done as:

```
ICmpInst* int1_5 = new ICmpInst(*label_4, ICmpInst::ICMP_EQ, int32_X, const_int32_1, "");
```

`ICmpInst` is a class that's part of the C++ API used to create `icmp` instructions. A good reference for the C++ API is the [Programmer's manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html).

Comment: Thank you for replay.But Can you tell me When and how to use the LLVM C++ API?

Comment: @user1406531: I hope you realize that your question is overly general. Why do you use LLVM at all? To what end? What do you plan to build on top of it? If you have exact answers for these questions, I think that after spending some time reading the LLVM tutorial and documentation, you will realize how the LLVM C++ API can help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CPP backend (`llc -march=cpp`) to find out the mapping from any given IR to the C++ API.

UPDATE: the cpp backend is no longer available.

Comment: At least for `llc` version `6.0.0` (obtained by running `llc --version`), the `-march` flag no longer takes `cpp`.

Comment: @Matthew yes, it was, sadly, removed long ago since nobody wanted to maintain that backend.